# Click image file in webbrowser without a class or ID tag using VBS

Tags: vbscript

Below is the tag from which i want to click an image file which will navigate to another link in a web browser (IE), [I tried using the destination link, but due to the limitation i am not able to paste the direct URL]

Below the WEb tag

```
<td class="Btext4" align="center" style="border-top-style: none">
 <img onclick="appSubmit('/Web/portlets/applications/redirect.jsp?PARAM=26','26','_blank')" class="applinklnh" src="/ABCD/Content/images/launch_4_june.gif" alt="Launch IPMS" width="94" height="36" border="0" style="cursor:pointer;">
</td>
<td class="Btext4" align="center" style="border-top-style: none">
 <img onclick="appSubmit('/Web/portlets/applications/redirect.jsp?PARAM=26','26','_blank')" class="applinklnh" src="/ABCD/Content/images/launch_4_june.gif" alt="Launch TGIF" width="94" height="36" border="0" style="cursor:pointer;">
</td>
```

*Edited : Tags added to get a clear id on where i am stuck

Till not i am able to code this much, and many attempts later I am not able to move ahead

```
            Dim objIE
            Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

            objIE.Visible = True
            CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate "Internet Explorer"
            objIE.Navigate  "https://www.website.net/"



            While objIE.Busy
            if x = vbNo then
                WScript.Sleep 100000000
            Else
                WScript.Sleep 10
            End if

            Wend

            objIE.Document.getElementById("USER").value = "username"
            objIE.Document.getElementById("PASSWORD").value = "password"
            objIE.Document.getElementById("login_button").click

            While objIE.Busy
              WScript.Sleep 100
            Wend
```

Please help me where i am doing things wrong. THanks

Comment: Just so I understand the question, the title sounds like you want to click on an image file in a web browser without using class or ID tag in VBS, is that correct? Looking at the web tag, both the table tag and the image tag have a class name. If the VBS code is to click on that image, it would be easiest to use the class name with `.click` at the end like you did in your second code.

Comment: Yes it is correct, but there are two tags with the same class but directs to the different links.